# How could i set current_user in a specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my program, I have 3 models for User with different roles.

Basic User model for all users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  some validates and associations
```

Admin for users who have role == 'admin'

```
class Admin < User
  def channels
    Channel.all
  end
end
```

Developer for users who's role == 'developer'

```
class Developer < User
  has_many channels
end
```

I'm using devise with my user authorize.when a user logged in, i wanna specific current_user to be a instance of the right class by user's role.

So i could use user.channels to get the different collection of channels.

Can i do this in devise? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this question several weeks ago, with the [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

I added the type column into users table.Then rails can the specific model automaticly.

Admin and Developer all use the users table with the type of admin and developer.then when a user login rails will specific the right instance of its model.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an `admin` and `developer` column in your users table, or if you have more roles then create a separate Roles table. You could also use the handy [Rolify gem](https://github.com/EppO/rolify).

Then you can call this method on an user object: `user.has_role?(:admin)` which return true or false.